# Strictly increasing function: Convex and bounded above?

Tags: real-analysis

Is there a simple example for a differentiable function f(x) that has the following properties?

$f(0)=0$, $f(x) \to 1$ when $x \to \infty$, $f'(x)>0$ for all $x \ge 0$, $f''(x)>0$ for all $x \ge 0$.

Comment: Try to draw it: it must be continuous, it must approach $\;y=1\;$ *from below* (why?) and **convex upwards** ...can you see why it is impossible?

Answer (score 1):

There is no such function.

Using Taylor's theorem, there exists $\xi_x \in [x,2x]$ such that

$$f(2x) = f(x) + f'(x)x + \frac1{2}f''(\xi_x)x^2.$$

By hypothesis, we have $f''(x) > 0$. Hence,

$$f(2x) > f(x) + f'(x)x,$$

and

$$0 \leqslant xf'(x) < f(2x) - f(x).$$

If $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty}f(x) = 1,$ then $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty}[f(2x)-f(x)] = 0,$ and for any $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $K > 0$ such that if $x > K$  then

$$xf'(x) < \epsilon.$$

However, $f'$ is nondecreasing since $f''(x) > 0$. If $x_2 > x_1 > K$ we have $f'(x_2) \geqslant f'(x_1) > 0.$

Choose $x_2 > \epsilon/f'(x_1)$. Then we have a contradiction,

$$x_2f'(x_2) \geqslant x_2f'(x_1) > \epsilon.$$